# How to iterate an object in JSP to get the percentage?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets, percentage

I am working on servlet and jsp project. I am passing an object from servlet to JSP. And currently I am iterating that object and showing them in a table -

Below is my code in jsp -

```
<TABLE id="tableSMS" BORDER="1" CELLPADDING="3" CELLSPACING="1" style="text-align: center;">
    <TR style="color:#ffffff;background-color:#787878;">
        <TH>Hash Name</TH>
        <TH>Database Name</TH>
        <TH>Version</TH>
    </TR>
    <c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${reportCount.getHash().size() - 1}">
        <TR>
            <TD>
                    ${reportCount.getHash().get(i)}
            </TD>
            <TD>
                    ${reportCount.getDatabaseName().get(i)}
            </TD>
            <TD>
                    ${reportCount.getVersion().get(i)}
            </TD>
        </TR>
    </c:forEach>
```

And above code is working fine and I am able to show the data properly. Now what I need to do is -

`${reportCount.getDatabaseName().get(i)}` will return database name as `oracle` or `mysql` only. Now I need to calculate what is the percentage of `oracle` database. I will get the total number of records from `${reportCount.getHash().size()`. So if total number of records is `10` and oracle database is present `5` times, then the percentage should be `50%`.

Now I am not sure how would I calculate the above percentage using that object? And after calculating that percentage, I need to show the result in a new table which is shown below -

```
      <table>
          <tr>
          <th style="background-color: #E8E8E6;"><b>Oracle Database</b></th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
              <!-- I would like to show the percentage in this row -->
              <td>%</td>
          </tr>
      </table>
```

I am thinking I should iterate the `reportCount` object again in the above new table and extract the percentage here but not sure how would I do that? Can anyone provide an example?

**UPDATE:-**

Here is my bean code -

```
public class Response {
    private List<String> hash = new LinkedList<String>();
    private List<String> databaseName = new LinkedList<String>();
    private List<String> version = new LinkedList<String>();

    // getters and setters here

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three things as following:

1. Add the functions taglib:
   `<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>`
2. Add reportsCounts variable to requestScope instead of session if not required on any other page & use as following:
   `<c:set var="oracleDBCount" value="0" scope="page" />
   <c:forEach var="reportCount"
           items="${requestScope.reportCounts.databaseName}" varStatus="loop">
           <TR>
               <TD>${requestScope.reportCounts.hash[loop.index]}</TD>
               <TD>${reportCount}
                 <c:if test="${reportCount == 'ORACLE'}">
                       <c:set var="oracleDBCount" value="${oracleDBCount + 1}" scope="page"/>
                   </c:if>
               </TD>
               <TD>${requestScope.reportCounts.version[loop.index]}</TD>
           </TR>
       </c:forEach>`
3. Now display percentage as:
   `${(oracleDBCount / fn:length(requestScope.reportCounts))*100}%`

Comment: what is `reportCounts` here? Can you provide an example basis on my code? I guess something is missing here if I relate to my example

Comment: it's the same variable you were setting in session i set it in request within a servlet `request.setAttribute("reportCounts", dbDetails);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/dbDetails.jsp").forward(request, response);` let me know if anything is missing or not clear

Comment: I cannot use this as it is since my hash and databasename are list not a single value.. So I cannot do like this `${reportCount.hash}`.. Is there any way I can make this work basis on my example?

Comment: No what I am saying is -  In your example you are assuming - In this `${reportCount.hash}` hash is a String variable right? In my case its not string variable

Comment: check now, i have updated the above code in answers section. do let me know how it goes.

Comment: Yeah I was able to make it work.. There is one more thing.. How can I add multiple conditions in the if statement in JSTL? something like this - `if(a == 1 && b==2)` in JSTL? how would I do that?

Comment: You can just keep on adding more conditions as i have added `<c:if test="${reportCount == 'ORACLE' || reportCount == 'SQL Server'}">` it's simple just like we do in java

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49622/discussion-between-akiiddweeber-and-user3085390)

Answer (score 0):

Based on my experience, doing number-crunching on a JSP page can make it unreadable very quickly. Also you may encounter additional requirements in the future such as:

- Text matching (Are you guaranteed that the value is always "oracle"? Or can it become "ORACLE" or "Oracle"?
- What if there are zero reports? Then you will need an if-condition to prevent division by zero.
- If your client says "We have more report servers like MS, Postgres...can you show the percentage of those?"

Is it possible to do the computation inside the servlet while you are making the reportCount object?
Then you can pass the value inside a session attribute

```
request.getSession(true).setAttribute("oracleReports", "50%")
```

and then in the JSP output something like

```
<c:out value="${sessionScope.oracleReports}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Use [JavaScript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/DEFAULT.asp) for doing the operation, Here is the code***

Read the comments to understand the code.

> Add an id to the  so that i can read the inner content using
>   javascript. Appended id with the index so that each raw gets different
>   id's

```
<c:forEach var="i" begin="0" end="${reportCount.getHash().size() - 1}">
                    <TD id="databaseName<c:out value='${i}' />">
                            ${reportCount.getDatabaseName().get(i)}
                    </TD>
```

> Add Id to the  so that i can set values to the raw using
>   JavaScript

```
<tr>
     <td id="oraclePercentage">%</td>
     <td id="mySQLPercentage">%</td>
</tr>
```

> call the javascript function to set the values to the raw, as we don't
>   have any button to trigger we open a raw and add the JavaScript call
>   from the JSP so that the script is triggered every time the page loads
>   the raw.

```
<TR><TD><Script>setPercentage('${reportCount.getHash().size() - 1}');</script><TD><TR>
```

> what to do is defined here

```
<Script>
function setPercentage(var index){
  for(var i=0; i<index;i++){
     var documentType=document.getElementById("databaseName"+i).innerHTML;
     var oracleCount=0;
     var mySQLCount=0;
     if(vardocumentType=='Oracle')
       oracleCount+=(Number)1;
     else if(vardocumentType=='MySQL')
       mySQLCount+=(Number)1;
     document.getElementById("oraclePercentage").innerHTML=(oracleCount/index)*100;
     document.getElementById("mySQLPercentage").innerHTML=(mySQLCount/index)*100;
 }
 </script>
```